# Cannot count the number of lines in a text file in python

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, text-editor, text-widget

Recently I have been working on a GUI python plain text editor. The code calls the following function that is supposed to count the number of lines that have been entered into the text widget:

```
def numlines():
    targetline = textPad.get(1.0, END)
    targetline.split()
    lines = 0
    for line in targetline:
        lines += 1
    return lines
```

The code runs, however it does not give me the correct number of lines in the file. In fact, it appears the the number of letters per line and spaces affect the line count number (ex: On two lines I enter two letters. I get 6 lines). I can not find an explanation for this issue.

I am running on Windows 7 with python 2.7.9 and tkinter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
targetline.split()
lines = 0
for line in targetline:
    lines += 1
return lines
```

With:

```
return len(targetline.split('\n'))
```

#### Example

Let us create an example `targetline`:

```
>>> targetline="line 1\nline 3\nline 3"
>>> print targetline
line 1
line 3
line 3
```

Now, let's count the lines:

```
>>> len(targetline.split('\n'))
3
```

An issue that I haven't addressed here is what `textPad.get` actually returns.  Does it use `\n` for a line delimiter?  Does it provide a final `\n` on the last line?  These are issues that you will need to address before the code is correct.

#### Discussion

Consider this line:

```
targetline.split()
```

Let's apply that to our example from above:

```
>>> targetline.split()
['line', '1', 'line', '3', 'line', '3']
```

There are two things to note:

1. It splits, by default, on all whitespace.
2. It returns a list.  It does not alter `targetline`.

Now consider:

```
lines = 0
for line in targetline:
    lines += 1
return lines
```

Since `targetline` is unaltered by `split`, the `for` loop loops over every character in `targetline`.  Consequently, this loop counts every character in `targetline`.

It just want the length of an object, such looping is not needed.  The `len` function is simpler.

Comment: Thank you. It worked, but I had to add lines = lines -1 or the code added an extra line.

Comment: @PseudonymEnigma Very good.  That  would appear to mean that  `textPad.get` returns with a final `\n` character.